# Need explanation of following query for deleting duplicate records

Tags: sql, oracle10g

Can anyone explain how lead works here?

```
DELETE table_name
WHERE  rowid IN
       ( SELECT LEAD(rowid) OVER
                (PARTITION BY key_values ORDER BY NULL)
         FROM   table_name );
```

Also I want to know that `ROWID` has been used here however I feel rowid should be avoided as far as possible. Is it correct to use rowid, what are its consequences?

Apart from above questions, if I fire subquery only, I have observed that I get all null values then how it fetches duplicate records?

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with using `ROWID` this way. They can safely be used within the same statement. You should not retrieve it, store it somewhere and then re-use the stored value because ROWIDs *might* change for a row (so you could get a different row than originally retrieved) - but again inside one statement this is OK.

I think the `lead()` function is used incorrectly here. It returns the value of the "next" row based on the ordering provided. So it will essentially return all rowids of the table except the "last" one as there is no next row for it. I guess that's the NULL value you are seing.

So the statement will actually delete all rows from the table except the last one (because for that one, the rowid will be null).

I *think* the real intention was to delete duplicates from the table. Something like:

```
DELETE table_name
WHERE rowid NOT IN (select min(rowid) 
                    from table_name 
                    group by key_values)
```

Comment: the `lead()` function has one advantage over `min()`: it takes care of multiple duplicates.

Comment: Every row would produce the next row's `rowid`. That means the subquery, when run, should produce all the rowids except those for the first rows in every group, i.e. one rowid per group would *not* be returned. The outer query would delete rows with rowids as per the returned set, meaning one rowid per group would not be deleted. Can't see anything wrong/incorrect with that.